# Python:Trying to make a circle at a random spot, with a random radius, that is filled randomly with a set of given color. Stuck on color part

Tags: python, random, colors

# Heres what I have so far. The colorCircle(myTurtle) doesn't seem to work and I don't really know what to do. Kinda of an amateur, any tips would be appreciated.

```
def drawPolygon(myTurtle,sideLength,numSides):
    turnAngle = 360/numSides
    for i in range(numSides):
        myTurtle.forward(sideLength)
        myTurtle.right(turnAngle)

def drawCircle(myTurtle,radius):
    circumference = 2 * 3.1415 * radius
    sideLength = circumference / 360
    drawPolygon(myTurtle, sideLength, 360)

def colorCircle(myTurtle):
    x = random.random()
    y = random.random()
    myTurtle.up()
    myTurtle.goto(x,y)
    myTurtle.down()
    radius = random.random()
    color = [('white',0),('yellow',1),('green',2),('blue',3),('purple',4),('red',5),('black',6),('magenta',7),('pink',8),('brown',9)]
    random.randint(0,9)
    myTurtle.begin_fill(color)
    drawCircle(myTurtle)
```

Comment: See the edits to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
color = [('white',0),('yellow',1),('green',2),('blue',3),('purple',4),('red',5),('black',6),('magenta',7),('pink',8),('brown',9)]

random.randint(0,9)
myTurtle.begin_fill(color)
```

is equivalent to:

```
color = [('white',0),('yellow',1),('green',2),('blue',3),('purple',4),('red',5),('black',6),('magenta',7),('pink',8),('brown',9)]

4
myTurtle.begin_fill(color)
```

Because you don't assign the random number to a variable, 4 in the example, the random number is discarded.  Then you pass the whole list of colors as the argument to begin_fill().

To get the random color, you can do this:

```
colors = ['white', 'yellow'....]  #Note the change here.
rand_num = random.randint(0,9)
selected_color = colors[rand_num]
```

But, python makes things [easier](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) than that:

```
import random

colors = ['white', 'yellow'....]
selected_color = random.choice(colors)  #Pick a random element from the colors list
```

**Edit: =============**

However, you are trying to pass an argument to the `begin_fill()` function, yet `begin_fill()` does not accept any arguments.  By default, `begin_fill()` uses *black* as the fill color.  To set the fill color to something else, use one of these functions:

```
fill_color('red')  #Sets fill color.
color('red')       #Sets both pen and fill color.
```

Here are some examples of what you can do:

```
import turtle
import random

def drawPolygon(myTurtle,sideLength,numSides):
    turnAngle = 360/numSides
    for i in range(numSides):
        myTurtle.forward(sideLength)
        myTurtle.right(turnAngle)

def drawCircle(myTurtle, radius, fill_color="blue"):
    circumference = 2 * 3.1415 * radius
    sideLength = circumference / 360
    myTurtle.color(fill_color) #color() sets pen and fill color

    myTurtle.begin_fill()  #The next shape that is drawn will be filled.
    drawPolygon(myTurtle, sideLength, 360)
    myTurtle.end_fill()  #Disable filling.

def getRandomColor():
    colors = ['yellow', 'green', 'blue']
    rand_color = random.choice(colors)
    return rand_color


rand_color = getRandomColor()
drawCircle(turtle, 40, rand_color)
turtle.exitonclick()
```

Or you could do this:

```
import turtle
import random

def drawPolygon(myTurtle,sideLength,numSides):
    turnAngle = 360/numSides
    for i in range(numSides):
        myTurtle.forward(sideLength)
        myTurtle.right(turnAngle)

def getRandomColor():
    colors = ['yellow', 'green', 'blue']
    rand_color = random.choice(colors)
    return rand_color

def drawCircle(myTurtle, radius):
    circumference = 2 * 3.1415 * radius
    sideLength = circumference / 360

    rand_color = getRandomColor()
    myTurtle.color(rand_color) #color() sets pen and fill color

    myTurtle.begin_fill()
    drawPolygon(myTurtle, sideLength, 360)
    myTurtle.end_fill()

drawCircle(turtle, 40)
turtle.exitonclick()
```

**===========**

Finally, color is not a good name for a list.  List names should be plurals, for example: colors, numbers, words; then you can write loops that look like this:

```
for color in colors:
    ...

for number in numbers:
    ...

for word in words:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't assign your random number to anything

```
random.randint(0,9) 
#You just say okay give me random number from 0 to 9 and then don't do anything with it
```

Second problem is that you can't fill with `begin_fill(color)`, but you can type `begin_fill()` but the default fill color will be black. so what you need to do is something like this:
`color = [('white',0),('yellow',1),('green',2),('blue',3),('purple',4),('red',5),('black',6),('magenta',7),('pink',8),('brown',9)]
randomPos = random.randint(0,9) #We randomly choose which color will it be
myTurtle.fill_color(color[ randomPos ]) #We set fill color to color we previously chose
myTurtle.begin_fill() #We start to fill`

I hope I helped and if you have any questions, just ask me.